# PHP failed to read file when executed in PowerShell

Tags: php, file, powershell

I have a PHP script that read and modify the content of files to compile a set of js file (ie. minify). It works when I run it in webserver. But when I execute it in PowerShell, the file can't be read.

The purpose is to create an automate script to to build compiled js file for deployment.

Here is the PHP code I'm using:

```
$compiledFile = './compiled.js';
$files = array(
    'script/file1.js',
    'script/file2.js',
    'script/file3.js'
);
foreach($files as $file) {
    $file = '../'.$file;
if(!is_file($file)){
        //get here all the time when run in PowerShell
    continue;
}
$content = file_get_contents($file);
        $minifiedJs .= JSMin::minify($content);

}
file_put_contents($cachedFile, $return);
```

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the file path, but hours of searching no help.

Comment: Try to execute the file from the folder the script lies. Or change the paths to absolute paths.

Comment: @bansi simple enough, it works with your suggestion. I'm about to make PowerShell start a webserver. Thanks.